# Constructing loop coverage for nested conditional loops in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, while-loop, code-coverage

I am currently learning about code coverage testing, specifically loop coverage, in Java. From [context](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ecs252/Book/loopcov.html), loop coverage involves running a loop 0, 1 and >1 times. However, I've encountered a problem with a specific function structure that I'm trying to test.

The structure is as follows:

```java
function() {
    if(A){
        //do something here as well

        while(A){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

The while loop is nested within an if statement, both of which have the exact same condition A. This structure seems to prevent me from creating a test case where the while loop would execute zero times since the enclosing if statement will prevent entering the loop if A is false.

Given this structure, how can I construct test cases that provide loop coverage (0, 1, >1 iterations) for the while loop?

Edit: I'm sorry if the question is inappropriate or too stupid to be answered, please tell me what's wrong with this question and I will not ask similar questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a statement (or several statements) that change the value of `A` inside the loop, otherwise, once entered, it would be an infinite loop.

Two of these cases are easy:
For `1`, you need a value of `A` that's `true`, and some additional conditions that cause `A` to become `false` in the first iteration.
For `>1`, you need a value of `A` that's `true`, and some additional conditions that make sure `A` remains `true` in the first iteration of the loop, but presumably becomes `false` some time later.

For the coverage of `0`, in the sense that the loop's condition is evaluated but never entered, you have a problem. Assuming the "do something here as well" under the `if` does not change the value of `A`, there is simply no way to evaluate the loop condition but not enter it. This situation would require `A` to be `false`, but if it is, the loop won't even be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize an *object-oriented design*.

- *[Lesson: Object-Oriented Programming Concepts (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)*
- *[Wikipedia – Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)*

```java
boolean A() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0;
}

@Test
void B() {
    //do something here as well
}

@Test
void C() {
    //do something
}

void f() {
    if (A()) {
        B();
        while (A()) {
            C();
        }
    }
}
```